# Invalid IP address with InetPton() function

Tags: c, windows, winapi, winsock, winsock2

I am using the Windows OS and am coding in C, currently.

I am a complete beginner in socket programming, and have this following piece of code that is returning unwanted values.
(`MAXLINE` = 4096), and I have `CTR_SECURITY...` defined.

```
const char* IPADDRESS = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx";//IP address

int sockFileDescriptor = 0, n;
int sendbytes = 0;
SOCKADDR_IN servaddr = { 0 };

char sendl[MAXLINE];
char recvl[MAXLINE];
memset(sendl, 0, MAXLINE);

WSADATA wsa;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);

if (0 > (sockFileDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) { 
    printf("no socket"); 
    exit(-1); 
}

memset((char*)&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(1337);

int a = InetPton(AF_INET, IPADDRESS, &servaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);
if (0 >= a) {
    printf("inetPton %d, returnV = %d", WSAGetLastError(), a);
    exit(-1);
}

if (0 > connect(sockFileDescriptor, (SOCKADDR*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) {
    printf("connect wrong %d", WSAGetLastError());
    exit(-1);
}
sprintf(sendl, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");

sendbytes = strlen(sendl);
/*
if (_write(sockFileDescriptor, sendl, sendbytes) != sendbytes) {
    printf("error");
    exit(-1);
}*/

if (0 > send(sockFileDescriptor, sendl, strlen(sendl), 0)) {
    printf("sendGoneWrong");
    exit(-1);
}

memset(recvl, 0, MAXLINE);
while ((n = _read(sockFileDescriptor, recvl, MAXLINE - 1))>0) {
    printf("%s", recvl);
}
exit(0);
```

It returns `"inetPton 10022, returnV = 0"`.

I have tried other IP addresses, but none of them changed the result, making me believe I am not using the `InetPton()` function correctly.

By the way, in `InetPton()`, should I be using `servAddr.sin_addr` or `servaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr`?

Comment: The last argument is expected to be an `in_addr` structure. So you should pass only `&servaddr.sin_addr`.

Comment: Winsock error code 10022 is `WSAEINVAL` (Invalid argument). Note that `WSAGetLastError()` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_pton) as only being meaningful if `InetPton()` returns `-1`, not `0`.

Comment: On a side note: if you get this working, your code will still fail, because you are sending an HTTP 1.1 request without a *required* `Host` header, eg: `"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: HostnameOrIP:1337\r\n\r\n"`. Why are you doing this manually with Winsock instead of using [WinInet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/about-wininet) instead? See [HTTP Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/http-sessions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong string type. `IPADDRESS` is a pointer of `PCWSTR` type. So you should use  `PCWSTR` or `const wchar_t*` to define IPADDRESS.

Check the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings
[image]

After modifying that, you can go to next step.
[image]

Comment: OK this managed to do it, thanks a lot, for the little table and the doc links as well

Comment: @NWA_fan My pleasure! If this is the answer, please accept it for guidance for who has same question.

Comment: Rather than calling `InetPton()`, you should instead call `inet_pton()`, which takes a `const char*` string.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all this:

```
memset((char*)&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(1337);

int a = InetPton(AF_INET, IPADDRESS, &servaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);
if (0 >= a) {
    printf("inetPton %d, returnV = %d", WSAGetLastError(), a);
    exit(-1);
}
```

With this:

```
{
    addrinfo *result = NULL;
    addrinfo hints = { 0 };
    int ret = 0;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    ret = getaddrinfo(IPADDRESS, "1337", &hints, &result);

    if (ret == 0 && result != NULL) {
        memcpy(&servaddr, result->ai_addr, sizeof(servaddr));
        freeaddrinfo(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think I know too little internet stuff to even comprehend it.