InetPton() implies "127.0.0.1" is not a valid IP. Why?
I am trying to create a C program that opens a connection via TCP, but when calling InetPton with "127.0.0.1" as the IP, it returns 0, meaning the passed string is not a valid IP address.
Since InetPton requires a string formatted like this : ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd, I have also tried passing 127.000.000.001, which didn't work either.
The program is meant to run on x64 Windows.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <winerror.h>

int initWinsock() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (result != 0) {
        char buffer[1024];
        sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "WSAStartup fehlgeschlagen: %d\n", result);
        OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
        return 1;
    }
    OutputDebugStringA("[1/3] WSAStartup successful\n");
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
        if (initWinsock() != 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    
        const char* serverAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        int serverPort = 64263;
        char errorMessage[256];
    
        SOCKET clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            sprintf_s(errorMessage, sizeof(errorMessage), "Socket-Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            OutputDebugStringA(errorMessage);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            OutputDebugStringA("[2/3] Socket created successfully!\n");
        }
    
        //Server-Adress
        struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
        ZeroMemory(&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
        serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
    
        int result = InetPton(AF_INET, serverAddress, &serverAddr.sin_addr);
        if (result == -1) {
            char errorMessage[256];
            sprintf_s(errorMessage, sizeof(errorMessage), "InetPton-Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            OutputDebugStringA(errorMessage);
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        else if (result == 0) {
            sprintf_s(errorMessage, sizeof(errorMessage), "IP could not be parsed!\nLast WSAError: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            OutputDebugStringA(errorMessage);
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        else if(result == 1) {
            OutputDebugStringA("[3/3] Server defined successfully\n");
        }
    }


Can you please try to create a [mre] to show us. With emphasis on the minimal part.

Please don't omit the header files... you did include header files?

Thanks for the edit: this line OutputDebugStringA(("Socket-Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError())); gives two compiler warnings. Before then, initWinsock() fails with initWinsock() undefined.

@WeatherVane Thanks for the info, I fixed it, however this does not seem to cause the error.

We don't need to see your creation of the socket, or its destruction. But we do need to see your call to WSAStartup. The point of a [mre] is to show us the absolute minimal possible example that replicates the error you get, but nothing more than that.

Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/78223602/26993270

@user202311 Using UTF-16 did not work, but I found out that InetPton redirects to InetPtonW, so I changed it to InetPtonA, which works so far.
Thanks!

@Joelbu: I find it hard to believe that using UTF-16 does not work. Please [edit] your question to show how you are attempting it. I believe that changing const char* serverAddress = "127.0.0.1"; to LPCTSTR serverAddress = _T("127.0.0.1"); should work.

Turns out InetPton expects a UTF-16 string by default, so I just called InetPtonA, which expects a "normal" ASCII char*, so instead of calling
int result = InetPton(AF_INET, serverAddress, &serverAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);
which redirects to InetPtonW(),
I used
int result = InetPtonA(AF_INET, serverAddress, &serverAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);.

That means you configured your build with the UNICODE macro defined, so InetPton is really InetPtonW. You need to be careful as then all Windows API functions that expects characters or strings will be the wide-char variants. You could use the types and macros that make it transparent (like const TCHAR* serverAddress = T("127.0.0.1");); Or explicitly use the wanted functions with the A or W suffix; Or recreate the project as a non-unicode project; Or just remove the UNICODE macro from the project settings.

By the way, don't you get any build warnings (or even errors) when using the wrong type of strings? The compiler should really complain about this. Which happens for me.

If that's the problem, it would have been caught by your compiler. Heed your compiler's warnings, which may require enabling them! With gcc, I use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
